# Flathub is telling me do something for LibreOffice. And i honestly don't know how to do it

Tags: libreoffice, environment-variables

This is Ubuntu 18.10 dual booted with Windows 10.

Apparently the only way to get latest LibreOffice was either by Flatpak or downloading the zip from Official website.

What and where should make I changes according to below "Note" statement?

```
$ sudo flatpak install flathub org.libreoffice.LibreOffice
Installing in system:
org.libreoffice.LibreOffice/x86_64/stable        flathub 1bf7758dc1d7
  permissions: ipc, network, pulseaudio, wayland, x11, dri
  file access: host, xdg-run/dconf
  dbus access: ca.desrt.dconf, org.gtk.vfs.*
  dbus ownership: org.libreoffice.LibreOfficeIpc0
org.libreoffice.LibreOffice.Locale/x86_64/stable flathub 4a88b1bc88e1
Is this ok [y/n]: y
Installing: org.libreoffice.LibreOffice/x86_64/stable from flathub
[####################] 418 metadata, 4841 content objects fetched; 253117 KiB transferred in 776 seconds
Now at 1bf7758dc1d7.
Installing: org.libreoffice.LibreOffice.Locale/x86_64/stable from flathub
[####################] 10 metadata, 71 content objects fetched; 1021 KiB transferred in 7 seconds
Now at 4a88b1bc88e1.

Note that '/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share' is not in the search path
set by the XDG_DATA_HOME and XDG_DATA_DIRS
environment variables, so applications may not
be able to find it until you set them. The
directories currently searched are:

- /home/pranav/.local/share
- /usr/local/share/
- /usr/share/
```

In case if the case is closed, without me getting actual help: https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/av15lq/flathub_warning_help_need_some_help_screenshot/

Comment: @earthmeLon It would be a great help if u solve this in my case. (I will accept ur answer ... and u will gain points. :-D How about that? )  I am a newbie. So... I might mess something up.

Comment: You can actually use the snap version too (it's updated to 6.2), just: snap install libreoffice

Comment: Kinda sad looking here that the "answer" just said to use a crappier packaging system...but you're basically supposed to reboot before these directories appear, I think newer Flatpak versions might hint at this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know how to set Environment Variable. 
But u can use "**snap install LibreOffice**" by uninstalling Flapak's LibreOffice.
Snap also keep updating LibreOffice